# jax.ws.rs.Response Does Not return all JSON

Tags: java, json, jersey-2.0

I am wondering if there is some sort of internal limit to the depth of a JSON object that **jax.ws.rs.Response** can return?

I have an Invoice object that contains another object, and so on, down to about 4 levels.

When I examine the top-level object in the debugger, it is as I expected.   When I use GSON to create a JSON string, it is also as I expect.

But the response builder seems to stop at the 3rd level.  I have also tried the **@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON** annotation, but it does not make a difference.

```
    if (InvoiceDetail != null) {
        res.setInvoiceDetail(InvoiceDetail);          // <-- looks fine 
        String s = new Gson().toJson(InvoiceDetail);
        System.out.println(s);                        // <-- looks fine
    }

    return Response.ok(res, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();   // <-- only 3 levels
```